# How to use/import a github project into existing android studio project?

Tags: android, git, github

I am currently working on an android app. I decided to add some animation effects to it.

When I googled it, I came across this [GitHub Project](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)(I am new to GitHub).

I have downloaded the zip file and imported it into android studio using File-> Import Sample.

It created a new android studio project. I am not sure how I should use the new project to get the animation effects in my app.

Should I just copy paste the required modules and edit it to fit my app or is there some other way to do it?

EDIT:
Some websites that I referred say that dependencies should be added. What will the dependency for the given project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most libraries provide a gradle (or maven) dependency, you only have to add to your `build.gradle` e.g.

```
compile 'com.example.library:library:1.2.3'
```

For this project I could not find this dependency, so you could try these two approaches: [Import the library in Android Studio](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio). I never had to try these approaches, so I am not sure, if the are working.